# substituting valign through CSS

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to position content within a table row. The row in question in turn contains 2 other tables and 1 small thumbnail image (each within a table cell of course). The row was positioned using `valign="top"` till now. This worked well getting contents of all the three columns to the top.

However, I wanted to position it using CSS `position:relative; vertical-align:text-top;`

This positions the cell content well **if there is no thumbnail image**. However, once the image is included, the other columns are not positioned at all. See the image below.

[image]

<sup>*Sincere Apologies for the Shoddy Image Formatting.</sup>

I want the two tables as well as the thumbnail to be vertically aligned to the top.

Please note that all margins and paddings are set to 0 and the sizes in the image are actuals.

Does somebody know why my browser (Firefox) is behaving this way and how to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok got it! It seems that `vertical-align:text-top` aligns an element to the **top of the parent element's text** and not to the top of the parent element! Changing it to `vertical-align:top` did the trick :)